# Webmin install not successful on Rackspace CentOS VPS

Tags: webmin

I exactly followed Rackspace document here:
http://www.rackspace.com/knowledge_center/index.php/CentOS_-_Webmin_1.470

to install webmin on CentOS. Every step is successful, except, in the end, I can't access webmin using the following link:
https://50.57.109.50:10000

It's a fresh activated image.

Have you tried to install Webmin on Rackspace CentOS VPS?

---

I followed the instruction here:
http://www.webmin.com/firewall.html

As you can see the port 10000 is open. I can't even deploy webmin on CentOS. Can you help?

Thank you!

---

I use the http instead https, then it works~ 
I don't know why. really confusing~

Answer (score 1):

I can access it.

There are three problems I can think of.

1. You may be experiencing the SSL Warning, which is normal - just accept the certificate if your getting that.
2. You are behind a firewall, which requires opening the port to 10000.
3. A firewall is blocking port 10000. If you are using iptables you can run the following:

   iptables -I INPUT -p tcp --dport 10000 -j ACCEPT